# focus not work with flex-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There I'm use pseudo element for make a border in bottom of link.

but focus is not work when i click on it ..................................//....................................//..................................//....................................//

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

li {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}

li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
}

.l1::after, .l2::after, .l3::after, .l4::after, .l5::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    transform-origin: right;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.l1:hover::after, .l1:active::after, .l1:focus::after, .l2:hover::after, .l2:active::after, .l2:focus::after, .l3:hover::after, .l3:active::after, .l3:focus::after, .l4:hover::after, .l4:active::after, .l4:focus::after, .l5:hover::after, .l5:active::after, .l5:focus::after {
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: scaleX(1);
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="l1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="l2"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="l3"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="l4"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="l5"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you click on it? "It does not work" is not enough of a problem description. Also, what are the ....//.... in your post supposed to be?

Comment: this has nothing to do with flexbox, and li aren't focusable elements